# Search text and replace with regex - IndexOf

Tags: jquery

I have the following shortcodes/text content. 
The content has to be structured, [fullwidth] can only contain [column] shortcode and similarly [column] shortcode can only contain other shortcodes but not simple text line. If any found, should be wrapped in [column span="12"]anything found[/column]. Below is the code that needs to be converted with regex.

```
[fullwidth]
    1111 any random text line not wrapped in shortcode
    [divider value="80"]
     ********** The above 2 lines them wrapped in [column span="12"] above 2 lines[/column]

    [column span="6"]
       [divider value="80"]
        2222 any random text line not wrapped in shortcode
       [text] something [/text]
    [/column]

    [column span="6"]
        3333 any random text line not wrapped in shortcode
        [divider value="80"]
    [/column]

    4444 any random text line not wrapped in shortcode
    [divider value="30"]
     ********** The above 2 lines them wrapped in [column span="12"] above 2 lines[/column]
[/fullwidth]
```

so the final output will become like below:

```
[fullwidth]

    [column span="12"]
        [text]1111 any random text line not wrapped in shortcode[/text]
        [divider value="80"]
    [/column]

    [column span="6"]
       [divider value="80"]
       [text]2222 any random text line not wrapped in shortcode[/text]
       [text] something [/text]
    [/column]

    [column span="6"]
        [text]3333 any random text line not wrapped in shortcode[/text]
        [divider value="80"]
    [/column]

    [column span="12"]
        [text]4444 any random text line not wrapped in shortcode[/text]
        [divider value="30"]
    [/column]

[/fullwidth]
```

my original code is very complex and cant post here, it will confuse you. What I tried is to first get content within each [fullwidth] and ignore columns, so I can convert them, below is the code line..

```
var shortcode = replace( 'column', shortcode, function(){return ' ';} ).replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ').replace(/<p> +<\/p>/g, ' ').trim();
```

the above code gives me [fullwidth] and the code that is not wrapped in [column] and remove [column]. I have no idea how to achieve this, I would appreciate any help or starting point.

Comment: To simplify this, any content found in [fullwidth] content + columns [/fullwidth] should be checked if wraped in [column] if not wrapped, then needs to be wrapped in [columns span="12"]content[/column]... similarly anything found in [column]content[/column] not wrapped in shortcode should be wrapped in [text]content[/text] shortcode..